# DIfference in function signatures between C++11 and C++14

Tags: c++

I want access to a complete list of function signatures that were present in C++11 but removed in C++14 and also list of function signatures that were added in C++14.

I do not want to scrape the standard to look for the difference.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: I don't know of anyone who has catalogged the differences (well cppreference lists signatures with annotations such as "until c++11" but theyre spread all of the site, not in one neat list). May I ask why you want/need such a list?

Comment: why do you want it? What would that list be good for?

Comment: I am working on a project where I used a bunch of C++ functions which were in accordance to C++ 14 standard, but now our scope changed and we can only use functions present in C++ 11 standard. I do not want to look at each of the function signatures I utilized and compare it with the standard. Therefore, I was looking for a list that would guide me on what function signatures I can use and what function signatures I have to remove from my project. Hope this reply helps.

Comment: Couldnt you just compile against C++11 and fix the compilation errors you get?

Comment: @goodfellas95 compile your C++14 code as C++11 and the compiler will point out where it doesn't work. Then fix all compiler errors. Done.

Comment: That was my initial thought. But, I was asked to prepare a list for my team so I can set up some ground rules.

Comment: @goodfellas95 once you set your build system to build as C++11 I'd say that establishes the ground rules. If it doesn't compile it's not C++11. For further info, point people at http://cppreference.com .

Comment: Extending on @JesperJuhl 's comment, here is an example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector . All of the standard differences, for `std::vector`'s constructor anyway, are clearly marked. Breaking it down by function is probably the best way to do it; a global list of everything would be an unholy nightmare to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I have stumbled upon a link that clearly highights the difference between the two versions and is proving to be very informative to me.

I am posting it here so that if anyone has the same question as mine, they can refer here.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1319r0.html